# Jenkins, надо ли ставить на саму машину или можно в Docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins

Есть машина, на которой есть Docker, хотел туда поставить Jenkins, но в нем нет docker'a самого, любые вызовы `docker` выкатывают ошибку, что docker'a нет.

Соответственно вопрос: где должен находиться Jenkinks, на самой машине или в Docker'e, но нужно сделать какую-то магию?

И, почему-то, ставил MSBuild в Jenkins, а `dotnet build` тоже не работал, говоря, что `dotnet` - нет такой команды (может нужно сделать свой образ на основе jenkins, куда будут установлены все dotnet зависимости, а потом в jenkins'e будет работать `dotnet build`, но как быть с контейнерами? убить старые, запустить новые...)